# how to replace a substring inside an iframe tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the example below only one instance of substring (`~code`) is replaced by a variable value.

How to replace the same inside the iframe tag, i.e. `embed/~code` should be `embed/92xR2fjbeUE`

```js
let file = $('#store_vid').html();
let code = '92xR2fjbeUE';
file = file.replace('~code', code);
console.log(file);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='store' id='store_vid'>
<div class = 'vidwrap' data-code='~code'>
<iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/~code?rel=0&fs=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0'></iframe>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string)

Comment: @3limin4t0r - I see thanks. I'm surprised - that's such a minor task and I must study `63` answers. Not good for the reputation of this site.

Comment: That's not the fault of SO that such a widely sought after question isn't implemented by the language itself. You also don't have to look at all the answers. If you find that there are too many I suggest looking only at the top rated few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default js try to replace the first instance of substring only. You can extend the string type like this

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};
```

Use the above method instead of `replace`

```
'12sdasdsadasd12asdasda12asdad'.replaceAll('12','89')//returns 89sdasdsadasd89asdasda89asdad
```

In your example

```
    String.prototype.replaceAll = function (search, replacement) {
        var target = this;
        return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
    };

    let file = $('#store_vid').html();
    let code = '92xR2fjbeUE';
    file = file.replaceAll('~code', code);
    console.log(file);
```

Comment: In my example I'm getting the error - `replaceAll is not a function`

Comment: create it like i wrote before you use it

Comment: and I tried with 5 instances, all of them are replaced, not only the first, just the one inside `iframe` tag is not

Comment: i am getting it fine only

https://jsfiddle.net/8ws5cm6t/  check the fiddle console

Comment: do I really must create a new function? I suppose that a function for replcing all instances of substing already exists

Comment: Thats your choice. I just demonstrated it

Comment: Note that this answer doesn't escape special regex characters. Meaning that `"1*3".replaceAll("*", "2")` fails with *"SyntaxError: nothing to repeat"*.

Comment: Oops. I didnt notice that yet

Answer (score 2):

what I get by your question is, you want to replace ~code with your variable , and ~code is attributed to a div of yours. if you don't want to change the iframe src ~code then don't use code in if condition.

```
`<div class = 'vidwrap' data-code='~code'>`
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  var code = '92xR2fjbeUE';
  document.getElementById("vidwrap").setAttribute("data-code", code);
  let iframeAttrSrc = document.getElementById("iframe").src;
  
  if(iframeAttrSrc.includes('~code')){
    alert("true");
    var newSRC = iframeAttrSrc.replace("~code", code);
    document.getElementById("iframe").setAttribute("src", newSRC);
  }
  

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='store' id='store_vid'>
<div class='vidwrap' data-code='~code' id="vidwrap">
<iframe id="iframe" src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/~code?rel=0&fs=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0'></iframe>
</div></div>
```